# Dynamically loading xaml files via .cs

Tags: c#, silverlight

Is there any way how to load xaml file with .cs together from source? (source can be everything db,resource etc.)

Thx your answers

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that by using

[XamlReader.Load(stream);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx)

to load from a stream of `XAML` data.

Comment: Yes thats true but i want to do Load via .cs file.I have already used this method.